# Animate interaction is not working properly though CSS does

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to create a floating menu which floats right and turns vertical upon scrolling and passing a certain `div`. It worked properly using the CSS jQuery function: 
 
`$("#content ul").css({right: "-90%"});
$("#content ul li").css({"display": "block"});` 
Here's a demo - **[bin](https://output.jsbin.com/piluratopu)** 

Nonetheless, it doesn't look the best so I wanted it to be animated. Apparently looks even worse, seems as if code is operating something it shouldn't. If I animate only the first command - `$("#content ul").animate({right: "-90%"});` it animates properly (though, of course, it wouldn't animate upon scrolling back).
**[bin](https://jsbin.com/faxoluxone)** 
Any iedas? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use transition in css

```
#content ul{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align:center;
    width:600px;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s;
  transition: all 2s;
}

#content ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s;
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually have tried using transition, but unfortunately I added it only to one element each try (either the `#content ul` or the `#content ul li`).
I'll obviously accept that solution, though it's really interesting why the `animate` function doesn't work as expected.